# How to parse feet-inch string in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am stuck. This one is easy. But, it has become a nightmare to me.

I am not able to parse this string and store into two variable named `feet` and `inch`.

```
  var f = "5'9''"; // 5 feet 9 inch 

  var nn = f.indexOf("\'");
  var feet = f.substring(0, nn);

  var inch = f.substring(nn + 1, f.lastIndexOf("\'\'")-1);
```

The **output** of `inch` should be `9` but is `nil`.

Comment: @Regexident will it be 9 instead of 5 in last line.

Comment: @Adeel: Uh, correct. Typo. Fixed it, my bad.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

```
var f = "5'9''";
var rex = /^(\d+)'(\d+)''$/;
var match = rex.exec(f);
var feet, inch;
if (match) {
    feet = parseInt(match[1], 10);
    inch = parseInt(match[2], 10);
}
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/exitev/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/exitev/1/edit)

If you change the regex to

```
var rex = /^(\d+)'(\d+)(?:''|")$/;
```

...then it'll allow you to use either `''` or the more common `"` after the inches value.

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/exitev/2) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/exitev/2/edit)

Answer (score 2):

```
var f = "5'9''";
var a = f.split("'");
var feet = a[0];
var inch = a[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions will do the trick:

```
var f = "5'9''";
var match = f.match(/^(\d+)'(\d+)''$/);
var feet = +match[1],
    inch = +match[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `-1` from

```
  var inch = f.substring(nn + 1, f.lastIndexOf("\'\'")-1);
```

As `substring` *method* takes start index and end index. It should be :

```
 var inch = f.substring(nn + 1, f.lastIndexOf("\'\'"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the selected answer above is it doesn't match if there are no inches supplied. Here is a solution that handles both feet/inches or just feet.

```
  display( parse("5'9\"") );  
  display( parse("6'") );

  function parse(feetAndInches){
    var fAndI = feetAndInches.split("'");
    var feet = fAndI[0];
    var inches = fAndI[1] || "0";
    inches = inches.replace('"', '');
    var msg = feet+" feet, " + inches+ " inches";
    return msg;
  }

  function display(msg) {
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.innerHTML = String(msg);
    document.body.appendChild(p);
  }
```

Try it here: https://jsfiddle.net/dqeeysf6/3/