# Convert feet in 5'5" notation to cm with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, range

I have a lot of heights, in inches, which need to be checked if they are between other heights. However, the data isn't 100% perfect; sometimes the number appears as `5'5"` and sometimes `5' 5"` (with a space). The height that it appears between will also be varied, looking sometimes like `5'5" - 5'10"` and sometimes like `5' 5"-5' 10"` and sometimes like `5'5"-5' 10" Height`...you get the idea.

Thus, I am trying to build a function that will take the number like `5'5"` and confirm either `true` or `false` that the number is between a height range in the format `5' 5"-5' 10"`.

```
function checkHeight(userHeight) {

  var rex = /^(\d+)'(\d+)(?:''|")$/;
  var match = rex.exec(userHeight);
  var feet, inch;

  if (match) {
    feet = parseInt(match[1], 10);
    inch = parseInt(match[2], 10);
    console.log("feet = " + feet + ", inches = " + inch);
  } else {
    console.log("Didn't match");
  }

};

checkHeight("5' 5\"")
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292724/how-to-parse-feet-inch-string-in-javascript?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: The title suggests you want to convert to `cm` but the question seems more about checking if the value is in a range. There is no point on converting to `cm` to do that, just do it in `inches`: `(feet*12 + inches)`. No need to multiply by 2.54 or anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses a similar regex, but removes the `^` and `$` so the match can occur anywhere and adds a `\s*` so that there can be any amount of whitespace between the feet and inches. It also does the test in a simpler way and avoids converting to `cm` altogether:

```js
function checkHeight( userHeightStr, heightRangeStr ) {
    const [ userHeight, minHeight, maxHeight ] =
      [ userHeightStr, ...heightRangeStr.split('-') ].map( heightStr => { 
        const [ , feet, inches ] = heightStr.match( /(\d+)'\s*(\d+)(?:''|")/ );
        return feet*12 + +inches;
      } )
    ;
    console.log( 'Heights in inches: ', { userHeight, minHeight, maxHeight } );
    return minHeight <= userHeight && userHeight <= maxHeight;
}

console.log( checkHeight("5' 4\"","5'  5\" - 6' 1\" Height") ); // false
console.log( checkHeight("5' 5\"","5'5\" - 6' 1\" Height") ); // true
console.log( checkHeight("5'10\"","5'5\"-5' 10\"") ); // true
console.log( checkHeight("5'11\"","5'5\"   -5' 10''") ); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this, using the suggested regex at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292724/how-to-parse-feet-inch-string-in-javascript?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

```js
    function checkHeight(userHeight,heightRange) {
      var heightRangeArr = heightRange.replace(/\s/g,'').toLowerCase().replace('height','').split('-');
      var heightRangeStart = heightRangeArr[0];
      var heightRangeFinish = heightRangeArr[1];
      var userHeight = userHeight.replace(/\s/g,'');
      if (convertToCm(userHeight) >= convertToCm(heightRangeStart) && convertToCm(userHeight) <= convertToCm(heightRangeFinish) ) {
        console.log(true);
      } else {
        console.log(false);
      }
    };
    
    function convertToCm(inchInput) {
      var rex = /^(\d+)'(\d+)(?:''|")$/;
      var match = rex.exec(inchInput);
      var feet, inch;
    
      if (match) {
        feet = parseInt(match[1], 10);
        inch = parseInt(match[2], 10);
      } else {
        console.log("Didn't match");
      }
      cmConvert = ((feet * 12) + inch)*2.54;
      console.log('*** *** ***');
      console.log(cmConvert);
      return cmConvert;
    }
    
    checkHeight("5' 5\"","5'5\"-5' 10\" Height");
```